# error document.registerElement is not a function console chrome in Debugging extensions Adobe CC application HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, adobe, adobe-premiere

i develop extension adobe by [link](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/creativesuite/articles/a-short-guide-to-HTML5-extensions.html)

port debugging is enabled and running but in console chrome error

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.registerElement is not a function
at Object.UI.registerCustomElement (inspector.js:2914)
at inspector.js:2918
at inspector.js:2921
```

and page not true for debugging

Answer (score 1):

I think that is depreciated see here [what-to-do-about-document-registerelement-deprecation-warning](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/thread/1517771/what-to-do-about-document-registerelement-deprecation-warning?hl=en)